# Importing Mousetrap in React project - Cannot read property 'bind' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, import, mobx, mousetrap

I'm trying to import mousetrap into a react project for some simple keyboard bindings.  I installed Mousetrap via yarn.  I don't have any errors importing, but the Mousetrap library object is undefined when I try to use it.  This is from my main App.tsx component

```
import Mousetrap from 'Mousetrap';

export default class App extends React.Component {
componentDidMount() {
    Mousetrap.bind(['left'], dataStore.pagination.prev());
    Mousetrap.bind(['right'], dataStore.pagination.next());
}

componenentDidUnmount() {
    Mousetrap.unbind('left', dataStore.pagination.prev());
    Mousetrap.unbind(['right'], dataStore.pagination.next());
}

public render() {
```

Here's the error I'm getting.
[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MHi0a.png)

I also tried initiating an Mousetrap object to use, but I get this error (plus there's nothing in the documentation saying I would need to).

```
const mousetrap: Mousetrap = new Mousetrap();
```

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aVU3P.png)

I'm using react, typescript, mobx, material-ui and several other libraries, and I'm quite new to all of them.  Any advice would be helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mousetrap has no named export, so your named import statement will result in `undefined`. You can import the library using:

```
import * as Mousetrap from 'Mousetrap';
```

Comment: Excellent.  That did it.  Is there something I may have missed in the documentation that would indicate this?  I had been going through this https://craig.is/killing/mice

Comment: nothing in the docs, since was probably written prior to named imports/exports, just looked in the main entry file to see how it was implemented

Comment: This does not work. If I `import * as Mousetrap from '/location/mousetrap.min.js';` then `Mousetrap` is a `Module` object – in which neither `Mousetrap.Mousetrap` nor `Mousetrap.bind` are defined.